# CodeIgniter: controller for getting values including images

Tags: javascript, php, forms, codeigniter

I have to submit my codeIgniter form which have dynamic columns. how can I get them from controller using a loop.

this is my view page

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('main_controller/do_insert');?>   
<div id="mainDiv">
 <div><input type="text" name="name0"/></div>
 <div><input type="file" name="img0"/></div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="add an entry" onClick="add('0')">
<input type="submit" value="save all"/>
<?php from_close();?>

<script>
function add(x)
{
 var count=x;count++;
 var str1="<div><input type='text' name='name"+count+"'/></div>"
 var str2="<div><input type='file' name='img"+count+"'/></div>"
 var str3="<input type='button' value='add an entry' onClick='add(`1`)'>";
 $("#mainDiv").append(str1+str2+str3);
}
</script>
```

note: the value of 'x' may not work properly but its not relevant here, can fix it by a global variable.

My problem is that how can i code controller for getting all the values  including images and save them to table, while submitting the form.

Comment: use ajax and redirect to the required controller

Comment: correct this `from_close();` as `form_close()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my suggestion, 
use file name as array field like.

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('main_controller/do_insert');?>   
    <div id="mainDiv">
     <div class='group'>
      <div><input type="text" name="name[]"/></div>
      <div><input type="file" name="img[]"/></div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="add an entry">
    <input type="submit" value="save all"/>
    <?php from_close();?>
```

> Script look like..

```
<script>
 $('#add an entry').on('click', function() {
        var cloneRow = $('.group').clone();
        cloneRow.find("input").val("").end();
        cloneRow.appendTo('#mainDiv');
</script>
```

> then in controller:

```
foreach($this->input->post() as $post){
//do action on your data...here
}
foreach($_FILES['userfile'] as $key => $value)
{
 //images data
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$i = 0;
foreach($this->input->post() as $post) {
            echo $post; //Or echo $this->input->post('name'.$i);
            print_r($_FILES['img'.$i]);
            $i++;
        }
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it’s always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).